# Error when following along with the tutorial on the Django website

Tags: python, django

I am following the django tutorial [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/intro/tutorial01/). I have copied everything exactly. After the part where you enter the python manage.py sql polls command, it returns:

```
Error:App with the label polls could not be found. Are you sure yuor 
INSTALLED_APPS setting is correct?
```

I have the site installed in /home/kevin/crossen/crossen, and the dir listing is

```
__init__.py
__init__.pyc
manage.py
polls(dir)
settings.py
settings.pyc
testdb(sqlite3 database)
test.db(0bytes)
urls.py
urls.pyc
```

and the end of my settings.py file looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS=(
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'crossen.polls'
)
```

The crossen.polls following the mystie.polls convention found in the guide. I have tried it with just polls, same error. Not sure whats wrong, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Polls dir is:

```
__init__.py
__init__.pyc
models.py
models.pyc
tests.py
views.py
```

Comment: What is the content of polls directory, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is there an `__init__.py` file in the `polls` directory?
- Is `/home/kevin/crossen` on your python path?

To check the path, do:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.path"
```

Comment: I have added /home/crossen/crossen to the path, still have the same error

Comment: I assume you mean /home/kevin/crossen ? If I understand your directory layout correctly, it is /home/kevin/crossen, NOT /home/kevin/crossen/crossen that should be in python's path.

Comment: sorry, mistype, it is home/kevin/crossen

Comment: So /home/kevin/crossen is now an item in the sys.path list?

Comment: You say: "I have added ... to the path". By this, do you mean the system PATH or the python interpreter's module search path?

Comment: manage.py is a wrapper for django-admin.py that should automatically add the corresponding site's packages to the site, so perhaps something else is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

open 'site/settings.py' file and change the INSTALLED_APPS setting to include the string 'your_app'